# Prevent user from entering future date angular 4

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, date

i have an object of dateOfBirth and i created an object of today's date with moment js 
but when i compare them it gives me an error even if date entered is smaller than today's date

**here is my html file**

```
<div class="form-group datepicker">
      <label for="dob">Date of Birth*</label>
      <div class="row input-group">
        <input
          ngbDatepicker
          #d="ngbDatepicker"
          #dobF="ngModel"
          class="form-control input-underline input-lg"
          id="dob"
          [(ngModel)]="dateOfBirth"
          placeholder="yyyy-mm-dd"
          name="dp"
          [ngClass]="{
            invalid:
              (dobF.value === null || isString(dobF.value) || (dateOfBirth.year > dobYear || dateOfBirth.month > dobMonth || dateOfBirth.day > dobDay) ) && dobF.touched
          }"
          required
        />
        <div class="input-group-append">
          <button
            class="btn btn-outline-secondary calendar"
            (click)="d.toggle()"
            type="button"
          ></button>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div
        *ngIf="
          (dobF.value === null || isString(dobF.value)  || dateOfBirth.year > dobYear || dateOfBirth.month > dobMonth || dateOfBirth.day > dobDay ) && dobF.touched
        "
        class="error"
      >
        Please enter a valid date of birth.
      </div>
    </div>
```

**here is my ts file where i defined my code of dob**

```
 public dateOfBirth: { year: number; month: number; day: number };
 public currentDate = moment().format("YYYY-MM-DD");
 public dobYear: any;
 public dobMonth: any;
 public dobDay: any;

  let obj = this.currentDate.split("-");
let obj2 = obj.map(Number);
this.dobYear = obj2[0];
this.dobMonth = obj2[1];
this.dobDay = obj2[2];
```

it is giving me an error because today's month is 02 so when i enter 2012-09-09 it gives me an error because 02<09 
so how to prevent this error?
can anyone help me? thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Surely the solution here is to simply use `Date` objects. You can compare them directly without parsing them, and use a reactive form with a custom Validator, which will also allow you to invalidate the form until a correct date is entered.

However, if you want to keep your current logic, you need to check if the year is wrong, then if the year is right BUT the month is wrong, then if the year and month are right but the day is wrong. It will wind up looking pretty illegible:

```
(dobF.value === null || isString(dobF.value)  || dateOfBirth.year > dobYear || (dateOfBirth.year == dobYear && dateOfBirth.month > dobMonth) || (dateOfBirth.year == dobYear && dateOfBirth.month == dobMonth && dateOfBirth.day > dobDay) ) && dobF.touched
```

Comment: I actually prefer Stefan's answer here, you can use built-in HTML validation with `max`.

Comment: worked like a charm thank you
god bless you :) @Will Alexander

Comment: I must say that Stefan's answer is superior. It will work if you use `new Date()` instead of a `moment.js` object.

Comment: it isn't working 
it is accepting future date and not giving any error

Answer (score 1):

Use `[max]` to prevent a user from entering a future date. There is no need to build this validator on your own.

See: https://material.angular.io/components/datepicker/api

HTML:

```
<input
  ngbDatepicker **[max]="maxDate"** ...
```

Controller:

```
public maxDate = new Date()
```

Comment: it doesn't work. i did it many times. when i write future date it doesn't do anything and accept it.

Comment: I'm using it and I can guarantee you, that it works. Maybe you are providing a moment data object and not an actuall date object.

Comment: i have done exactly like stefan but did not work 
is there any extra implementation of it? @Stefan

Comment: Does  your validation work at all (e.g. with required)?

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion would be as follows.

1. Since you are using date picker, disable the input field(mark it as readonly)
2. Set [maxDate]="maxDate" (Today is the current date which you can obtain by the below code)

   ```
    import * as moment from "moment";

    **Declare:-** 

    maxDate: {};
     today = new Date();

   constructor(){
       this.maxDate = {
         year: parseInt(moment(this.today).format('YYYY')),
         month: parseInt(moment(this.today).format('MM')),
         day: parseInt(moment(this.today).format('DD')),
       }
   }
   ```